# Android Studio Installation error

Tags: android

I installed android studio and when the application was started, it started downloading some packages.
But it fails to complete this download giving the error 
"The following SDK component was not installed: tools"

So i downloaded SDK tools 24.0.2 which is the latest one.But my android studio is still trying to download 24.0.1

This is the text from the show details section

Android SDK was installed to C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Android\sdk3
Refresh Sources:
  Fetched Add-ons List successfully
  Refresh Sources

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Installing Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.1
    Installed Android SDK Tools, revision 24.0.1
  Installing Android Support Repository, revision 11
    Installed Android Support Repository, revision 11
  Done. 2 packages installed.
The following SDK component was not installed: tools

So what should i do

Comment: Go to SDK Manager and check for that component.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that to stop auto updating of android studio, like this -->
[do follow the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EALO.png)

hope this will help